# C# - Convert PointF to Point

Tags: c#, point, system.drawing

I think it's a simple question but I cant figure it out.

```
//verifica qual o ponto mais proximo do centroide_circulo
PointF ponto_mais_proximo = pontos_medios.OrderBy(x => Math.Pow(x.X - centroide_circulo.X, 2) + Math.Pow(x.Y - centroide_circulo.Y, 2)).FirstOrDefault();

LineSegment2D linha_circulo_vertice = new LineSegment2D(centroide_circulo, ponto_mais_proximo);
```

> cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.PointF' to 'System.Drawing.Point'

My question is how can i convert it? ponto_mais_proximo in the first line of code needs to be PointF.

Comment: what type is `pontos_medios`? Any change you could translate your comments into english, makes it a bit easier to read potential comments that could have a benefit to the question at hand

Comment: Use Point.Round(PointF) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.round(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`Point.Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point.round):

```
LineSegment2D linha_circulo_vertice = 
    new LineSegment2D(centroide_circulo, Point.Round(ponto_mais_proximo));
```

> Converts the specified PointF to a Point object by rounding the Point values to the nearest integer.